# Adding Video in Placeholder

Tags: android, imageview, placeholder

I want to use a video placeholder before the actual images loads up. I am using a Fullscreen ImageView to load the image but till the time image is loaded to the imageview, i want to show a placeholder video at that place. I am not sure, even if it is feasible or not. If in any case it is feasible, would be looking for the way to get out of this.

Comment: Why do you want to use Video Placeholder instead of Image Placeholder?

Comment: @ManzurulHoqueRumi It's a very short video showing animation for the loader

Comment: What about an animated gif placeholder?

Comment: @MidasLefko If that can be used, i can convert my video file to animated gif placeholder file. Any shot how to use that in my case?

Comment: use `FrameLayout` with two children: `ImageView` and `VideoView`

Comment: I would recommend using a [ProgressBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar) which is visible in place of the image while the image loads. Then hide the ProgressBar and show the ImageView when the image is loaded.

Comment: Check glide https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki

Comment: @MidasLefko i am using my placeholder like this RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
                        requestOptions.placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder);
                        Glide.with(getActivity())
                                .setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)
                                .load(savedArticles.get(0).getArticleSecondImage())
                                .into(lsFirstArticleIv);                                                   What should be my code now to load an animated GIF as the placeholder?

Comment: @pskink and how to change between VideoView and ImageView?

Comment: `ViewGroup#removeView` / `View#setVisibility` / `View#bringToFront`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this working, i was able to use GIF animation as my Placeholder using Glide.
Loaded GIF file from drawable resource.

```
RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
requestOptions.placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder);
Glide.with(context)
    .setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)
    .load(articlesListChild.get(position).getArticleImage())
    .thumbnail(Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.logo_anim_full))  // This line did the magic
    .into(imageContentIv);
```